# *box for images displayed as a post's [gallery]

Tags: images, gallery, thickbox

I can remember that (at some time) there was a box display (LightBox? GrayBox? ThickBox?) for displaying images when clicking on them.

Example:
http://opus-irae.com/blog/2011/11/photos-blast-of-eternity-2011/

I want the image to appear in a *box I click on it, with "next" and "prev" buttons to navigate through the gallery. The images are included with the `[gallery]` tag, by the way.

How can I achieve this? Is this a (non) feature of my theme? Or a WordPress feature? Or do I need a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the "Auto ThickBox Plus" plugin, although I am not satisfied with the layout and look of ThickBox…